# Node POST request not working for Instagram API: This client has not been approved to access this resource

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to do some simple GET/POST requests with Instagram's API. I have a get request that uses the request node module and it works fine. I have an access token attached to the end of my query `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[user]/media/recent?[access_token]`

```
request(
    {url, method: "GET"}, function(error, response, body) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(body)
    console.log(parsed.data[5])
});
```

However, when I try to make a post request in postman with the following query:

```
 https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/[media-id]/likes?[authID]
```

it displays

> ```
> {"meta":   
> {"error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException","code":400,"error_message":"This
> client has not been approved to access this resource."}}
> ```

I'm in sandbox mode and the docs specify that you can do up to 30 POST req's to an endpoint an hour with no live account. Can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of scopes you have requested for this token? Your GET request requires just **public_content** permission, while POST likes requires **likes** [scope](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/#post_likes). You should add this permission to scope list during [authorization](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/).

Comment: Yep, I did some additional research on this topic and it appears it cannot be done as of November as Instagram locked down their API. "Basic" permissions in sandbox only allows you GET requests. Oh well :(

Comment: Hi @Justin can you please give me a link where you learn it? thanks

Comment: @magik In the instagram developer API docs, under https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/, it notes: if you plan on asking for extended access such as reading public content, liking, commenting, or managing friendships, you will need to specify these scopes in your authorization request. Note that in order to use these extended permissions, you must first submit your app for review. Here are the scopes we currently support: basic (granted by default), and everything else requires instagram auth.